# Display QML rectangles on video stream based on object recognition

Tags: qt, computer-vision, qml, qt5

I have a video stream as describe in [Qt Video Overview](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/videooverview.html), using the `MyVideoProducer` mechanics.  The source images are analyzed and I have a list of connected components (x,y,width,height) and I want overlay rectangles on the video.

Can I do this by sending a list of rectangle co-ordinates to QML and have it place the rectangles or do I need to create my own overlay images?

I looked at the QtQuick particle system but it doesn't seem to fit.  Other questions have the layout of the rectangle managed by Qt/Qml, but I need the rectangle to be placed according to the co-ordinates that the vision pipeline has determined in C++ and sent to the QML front-end.  They will be stale/related to the video frames.

There is [an example](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.9/qtmultimedia-multimedia-video-qmlvideo-example.html), but the overlay is unrelated to the video. I think I need an overlay that is synced to the `onNewVideoContentReceived()`. QML won't be able to determine how to keep any list of rectangle in sync with the video easily.

Comment: Better consider Qt3D. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-geometry.html But the subject would not fit in a couple of lines of text here to describe and apply to your question.

Comment: Sounds like you could generate a model on the C++ side, and use a Repeater or something on the QML side to generate the Rectangles.

Comment: @artlessnoise It will end up in GPU after some preprocessing anyhow. What exact transform of the scene is and if your shapes have any height is just a detail. Other than that you could consider https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwindow.html#afterRendering and like signals for the synchronization with graphics output. I do render my own programmatic drawing with both after and beforeRendering slots to insert it there at the right time.

Answer (score 1):

I just modified the original buffer creation, debayered from a camera, to draw the rectangles myself in the RGBA format.  It avoids the synchronization issue of the video frame with the object location data.  I did not use alpha but just replacement of pixels.  For my content, the amount of boxes versus the video area was not great.  With alpha rectangles and a lot of objects, it may be more efficient to involve a GPU.  In fact, you could used fixed size squares and not the CCL bounded region and this might be significantly faster with a GPU.

A QML solution would be more elegant, but this solution works.

---

Alternative options are [`QVideoFrame::setMetaData`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideoframe.html#setMetaData), this can tie the CCL QRect list to the frame, so that the association is clear and tied to the frame.  The method `onNewVideoContentReceived()` of the `MyVideoProducer` could render the rectangles from C++.

Another option is [QAbstractVideoFilter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractvideofilter.html), which will modify the original buffer to add additional data to the images presented.  This is easy to enable/disable via the QML front end.

All solutions rely on C++ so it is not easy to change coloring, etc in QML.  For example if the object has a recognized property such as 'male', 'female', 'cat', 'vehicle', etc the QML could update the highlighting appropriately and maintain an accounting of the object types.